# Use only internal display

Tags: display

I charge my Mac through an external display's using USB-C port. The external display has one another PC computer connected to it too.

When the connected PC goes to sleep, my Mac's screen pops up on the external display.

How can I set things up such that my Mac use the external monitor only for charging and not for display.

Comment: This can be configured on your external display. Make sure your external display is not set to switch to a different source automatically.

Comment: In mac I'm not able to configure it, the monitor auto switches.

Comment: I found the setting to turn the auto switching off, nice.

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be configured on your external display and not on the connected device (Mac, PC or anything else).

Make sure your external display is set to not switch to a different source automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a charging-only cable.
These don't have the data lines connected, only the power lines.

Electronics Stack Exchange has a question on methods to correctly identify these - [How can I tell charge-only USB cables from USB data cables?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/140225/how-can-i-tell-charge-only-usb-cables-from-usb-data-cables)